# POST to PHP Session doesnt work on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, php, iphone, session, post

Im doing a form POST submit from javascript to PHP and it works fine on desktop but doesnt post the values on iPhone? They're stored as PHP session variables in the PHP but it seems theyre not posting even out of session store. Has anyone seen this issue before?

Javascript:

```
 var $form = $('<form method="POST" action="profile.php"></form>'); 
 $form.submit(function () { 
 var input = $("<input>") 
 .attr("type", "hidden") 
 .attr("name", "email").val(email); 
 $(this).append(input); 

 return true; 
 }); 
 $form.submit();
```

PHP:

```
 if(isset($_POST['email']))
 {
 $myEmail = $_POST['email'];
 $myEmail = $_SESSION["email"] = $_POST['email'];
 $myEmail = $_SESSION["email"];
 }
 else{
 $myEmail =  $_SESSION["email"];
 }
```

Works fine on desktop. No values at all on iPhone. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the form field named "username"? You test for it in the PHP code but going off of what you've pasted here that if test will always fail.

Comment: apologies, the code i posted here was incorrect. It is set up properly as i've now corrected above. It works fine on desktop, but not iPhone.

Comment: Ah! one of the variable names did have a typo. thanks, what you said led me to identifying it. It works fine now. I think it was showing on desktop because it had been stored in the session previously. Thanks.